# Add files to Copy Bundle Resources in multiple targets

Tags: xcode

Everytime I add new files in Xcode it only adds the new files in the main target, where I have multiple targets in the project. Is there a way to add new files to all the targets in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's quite easy to do. As you add new files, you can select multiple targets in the dialog box once you choose to create a new file:

I'm creating a new text file to add to all Copy Bundle Resources.
[image: I'm creating a new text file to add to all Copy Bundle Resources]

Make sure you check all the targets you want!
[image: Make sure you check all the targets you want!]